# What does set -e do?

Tags: bash

I have a script that I found and I am trying to get it to run, it just downloads and install Apache runtime libraries. The first line is `set -e` and it is causing an error; what does `set -e` do?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> This builtin is so complicated that it deserves its own section.
>
> set
>   allows you to change the values of shell options and set the
>   positional parameters, or to display the names and values of shell
>   variables.

The `-e` option

> -e
>
> Exit immediately if a pipeline (see Pipelines), which may consist of a
>   single simple command (see Simple Commands), a subshell command
>   enclosed in parentheses (see Command Grouping), or one of the commands
>   executed as part of a command list enclosed by braces (see Command
>   Grouping) returns a non-zero status. The shell does not exit if the
>   command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a
>   while or until keyword, part of the test in an if statement, part of
>   any command executed in a && or || list except the command following
>   the final && or ||, any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the
>   command’s return status is being inverted with !. A trap on ERR, if
>   set, is executed before the shell exits.
>
> This option applies to the shell environment and each subshell
>   environment separately (see Command Execution Environment), and may
>   cause subshells to exit before executing all the commands in the
>   subshell.

Source: [www.gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)

**Edited due to @psusi's comment below.**

Additionally you can read the bash's manual page

```
man bash
```

at the section: SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS

or issue

```
help set
```

for a short help message.

Comment: Since it is a builtin command, you want `help set` and the full bash manual is `info bash`, if you have bash-doc installed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @psusi. `help set` and/or `man bash` are the correct ones for `set` .

Answer (score 17):

`set -e` in short, when it is at the top of your bash script, tells script to exit as soon as any line in the script fails (with some exceptions listed in the manual.)[1]

As a debugging option, it's often used with `set -x`, which is to print each expanded command line before execution with a "+" sign.[2]

See more at:

[1] https://www.peterbe.com/plog/set-ex

[2] http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html

Comment: Thanks for simple explanation. I often see set -xe in Dockerfiles and now I know the reason :)